# I want to know the HTTPSConnection redirected to which URL?

Tags: android, facebook

I am building an application that uses the Facebook Graph API.

To get the access token I should send the following request

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
    client_id=...&
    redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback

It redirects to the redirect_uri with the code to be used as access token.

How can I capture that the HttpsURLConnection is redirected and how to get the code?

Is it possible or I need to have server that gets the access token?

Comment: If You don't want to store secret in your APP you probably have to use backend server. You can check this code for example http://code.google.com/p/triker/

Answer (score 0):

download the official [Facebook for Android SDK](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/) and check out the examples